# Store Dynamic Menu data into a json from MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

**EDITED**

I have a self referencing table storing dynamic menu data like following.

```
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|id  |  name          | link                | parent_id  |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|1   |  Setup         | NULL                | 0          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|2   |  Common_Setup  | NULL                | 1          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|3   |  Management    | NULL                | 0          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|4   |  Gender        | setup/gender        | 2          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|5   |  Approval      | management/approval | 3          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------| 
|6   |  EEE           | eee                 | 0          |
|----|----------------|---------------------|------------|
```

Now i want to store them as a json in PHP(Laravel) variable, like the following structure,

```
[
   {
       id       : 1,
       title    : 'Setup',
       children : [
           {
               id       : 2,
               title    : 'Common_Setup',
               children : [
                   {
                   }
               ]

           }
       ]
   }
]
```

As, there is no limit for the children level layer, i think its better to call a recursive method or something like this.

```
function hierarchy($allPage, $parent = 0) {
    foreach ($allPage as $page) {
        if ($page->parent_id === NULL) $page->parent_id = 0;
        if ($page->parent_id === $parent) {
            $children = hierarchy($allPage, $page->id);
        }
    }
}


function getPages()
{
    $allPage = Page::all():
    $dynamicMenu = hierarchy($allPage, 0);
    echo "last: ".$dynamicMenu;
}
```

In the $dynamicMenu, i want to store the final JSON structure. Can anyone tell me how i can get this desirable structure ?

Comment: As you've provided some sample code: what does it do? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
I have solved it by the following way:

```
function getMenuTreee($arrayForPages, $parent = 0)
{
    $menuTree = [];
    foreach ($arrayForPages[$parent] as $page) {

        $newMenu = new \stdClass();
        $newMenu->id = $page['id'];
        $newMenu->title = $page['name'];
        $newMenu->url = $page['link'];
        // check if there are children for this item
        if (isset($arrayForPages[$page['id']])) {
            $newMenu->children = $this->getMenuTreee($arrayForPages, $page['id']); // and here we use this nested function recursively
        }
        $menuTree[] = $newMenu;
    }
    return $menuTree;
}



function getPagess(Request $request)
{
    $arrayForPages = [];
    $allPage = Page::all();

    foreach ($allPage as $page)
        $arrayForPages [$page->parent_id][] = $page;

    $dynamicMenu = $this->getMenuTreee($arrayForPages);
    return $dynamicMenu;

}
```

Thanks who have posted their own answers :)  Those helps me to find out this solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get your data from the DB like this:

```
$data = Model::all();
```

or

```
$data = DB::table('model')->get();
```

Change it to

```
$data = Model::all()->keyBy('id');
```

or

```
$data = DB::table('model')->get()->keyBy('id');
```

This way the $data collection will be indexed by the `id` column from the database.

Now you don't need a recursive function to construct a recursive structure. Just some simple loops are needed:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $item->children = [];
}

$tree = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item->parent_id === 0) {
        $tree[] = $item;
    } else {
        $data[$item->parent_id]->children[] = $item;
    }
}

foreach ($data as $item) {
    unset($item->link, $item->parent_id);
}

echo json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Setup",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Common_Setup",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Gender",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Management",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Approval",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "EEE",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Comment: It returns error: "ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: @NazemMahmud - It is because I used `NULL` instead of `0` to determine root nodes (`if ($item->parent_id === NULL)`). That is fixed now.

Comment: I was wondering how that could happen, since I've tested my code with sample data from your question. Turns out, you have changed the question. Please never do it again on SO, after working answers have already been posted. You should be able to adjust the code from an answer.

Comment: At first i tried with your code  without changing anything where NULL was allowed. After getting the error, i tried by changing the fields and new process. Thanks for your idea too :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
function hierarchy($parent=NULL) {
    $return=array();
    $return=(array)DB::table('Page')->where('parent_id',$parent)->get();
    for($i=0;$i<count($return);$i++){
        if($return[$i]['parent_id']!=null){
            $return[$i]['childrens']=hierarchy($return[$i]['parent_id']);
        }else{
            $return[$i]['childrens']=array();
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: It returns error: "ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Undefined offset: 0"  at the following line:  if($return[$i]['parent_id']!=null){

Comment: `parent_id` is **null** or **empty** value in your table. i think parent_id value stored empty in table. `function hierarchy($parent="") {
    $return=array();
    $return=(array)DB::table('Page')->where('parent_id',$parent)->get();
    for($i=0;$i<count($return);$i++){
        if($return[$i]['parent_id']!=null){
            $return[$i]['childrens']=hierarchy($return[$i]['parent_id']);
        }else{
            $return[$i]['childrens']=array();
        }
    }
    return $return;
}`

Comment: I have updated the parent_id column and replaced NULL with 0. I have edited the question for this. I also solved it already and provided that here as an answer. You can look that solution too. Thanks :)